# How can I code these constraints in CPLEX?

Tags: cplex

I am writing a model to minimize the overall cost, but I faced a problem when I wanted to write the constraints shown in the attached picture.

How to write these constraints in Cplex?

[image: Constraints]

with a lambda, it's from 0; 0,1; 0,2; ...; 1

I have tried to code it, but it gave me an error:

> Operator not available for float IN range

```
forall(i in items, t in times:(t - (tau[i] + (1 - lamda) * h[i])) in times)
    ct6:p[i][t - (tau[i] + (1 - lamda) * h[i])] + ((e[i] + n[i] * (1 - lamda)) * (S[i][t - 1] - S[i][t])) - sum(j in trucks) (p[i][t] * b[i][j]) <= d[i][t]; //(6)
forall(i in items, t in times:(t - (tau[i] + (1 - lamda) * h[i])) in times)
    ct7:p[i][t - (tau[i] + (1 - lamda) * h[i])] + ((e[i] - n[i] * (1 - lamda)) * (S[i][t - 1] - S[i][t])) - sum(j in trucks) (p[i][t] * b[i][j])  >= d[i][t];  //(7)
```